# How to add a build system that does nothing in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

The SublimeOnSaveBuild sublime plugin helps generate CSS file from LESS file, as the process triggered on build, it turns out I have to add a build system to use it, I added one and delete the default configuration but got error on build, any advice? I need the build system do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I have switched to the less2css plugin which works on saving.